# ASP.NET Web API Streaming a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, streaming

I am using Web API to serve the requests for files. File may be on disk or on some other server. The API controller sends a forward request or reads the file from the system and returns it.

```
    public  HttpResponseMessage GetResponse(string uri, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        try
        {
            string newUrl = MapUrl(uri);
            Stream responseStream = CreateResponse(request, newUrl);
            response.Content = new StreamContent(responseStream);
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            response.Content = new StringContent(ex.ToString());
            return response;
        }

    }
```

`CreateResponse()` either returns a `FileStream` or `GetResponseStream()` based on the current configuration.

No `Content-Length` header is being added as the file is being streamed, in the response headers I see `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header as expected.

But in case the file has to be served by reading from the filesystem IIS automatically adds the `Content-Length` header - **which should not have happened** as the file is being read as a stream by the code,

```
return new FileStream(newUrl, FileMode.Open);
```

any custom headers added show up confirming response was sent by the code and not IIS directly.

In  `global.asax` `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;`